# How do I make this CSS progress tracker responsive?

Tags: html, css

How can I make this CSS progress tracker responsive?

I want the "steps" to stack on top of each other when viewed on a screen that is too small to fit them horizontally.

Code snippet included below, or jsfiddle here if you prefer:https://jsfiddle.net/yr6kwzcv/

```css
/* Resets the ordered list styles and makes the list elements be displayed in a single line */
.track-progress {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.track-progress li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;

  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;

  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

/* Make it occupy all the available width */
.track-progress[data-steps="3"] li { width: 33%; }
.track-progress[data-steps="4"] li { width: 25%; }
.track-progress[data-steps="5"] li { width: 20%; }

/* Adds a "done" class to represent the progress */
.track-progress li > span {
  display: block;

  color: #999;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.track-progress li.done > span {
  color: #666;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* add the arrows */
.track-progress li > span:after,
.track-progress li > span:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  border: solid transparent;
  border-left-color: #f0f0f0;
  border-width: 15px;
}

.track-progress li > span:after {
  top: -5px;
  z-index: 1;
  border-left-color: white;
  border-width: 20px;
}

.track-progress li > span:before {
  z-index: 2;
}

/* Make arrows match the color of the previous step and remove arrow from first element */
.track-progress li.done + li > span:before {
  border-left-color: #ccc;
}

.track-progress li:first-child > span:after,
.track-progress li:first-child > span:before {
  display: none;
}

/* Adds arrows appearance to the start and end */
.track-progress li:first-child i,
.track-progress li:last-child i {
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  border: solid transparent;
  border-left-color: white;
  border-width: 15px;
}

.track-progress li:last-child i {
  left: auto;
  right: -15px;

  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: white;
  border-bottom-color: white;
}
```

```html
 <ol class="track-progress" data-steps="3">
   <li class="done">
     <span>Site Information</span>
     <i></i>
   </li><!--
--><li class="done">
     <span>Data Source</span>
   </li><!--
--><li>
     <span>Final Details</span>
     <i></i>
   </li>
 </ol>
```

Here is the source of the code snippet I recreated above: https://coderwall.com/p/-7trcg/simple-css-only-wizard-progress-tracker

Comment: Please show us what you have tried to do to fix your issue.

Comment: This will require a change in the way you put the arrows, as when a step go below the one before, the previous step's arrow also goes down. ([See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Le1hdbvu/) (Reduce the width of the result's and the css' frame))

Comment: @MarkPerera thanks for the help. I was hoping to avoid media queries and just have it fluid in nature. But I'm new to responsiveness so I'm not sure if that is possible. Your solution does stack each step as needed, but the arrows are also forced onto the next line which I can't figure out how to stop happening.

Comment: @Ekyl I'm new to responsive coding, but I've tried adding `min-width: 300px;` to `.track-progress li` without luck -- this will stack them one by one, instead of all at once. Also I still have the problem of the ending triangles not staying with their correct element. I'm stuck for ideas.